# Cannot access class in test package from main package (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I have a maven project in eclipse with a folder structure are follows -

```
   - Project

    > src/main/java ..

    > src/test/java ..
```

I found that when I try to initialize any class in the test package from my code in the 
main package I get a classNotFoundException.

I want to know why this happens and what is the reason for not allowing access to test classes from the main package ?

Comment: have you imported that package to your main package?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your main code needs code in the test folder, then the code in the test folder is not a "test", it is main code.  The point of test is that it is independent from your main code and not an integral part.

Otherwise, if you really want to do it, look at the Run Configuration you are using to launch your program and set the classpath to include the test stuff.

Comment: Thanks.I never looked at this from the context you have explained.

Comment: How to config to run your main method using configuration any specific steps