# How can I access a junit class in main folder from Maven's test/java folder?

Tags: java, maven, junit4, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

How can I access a junit class which is having cucumber option configs in main folder from Maven's **test/java** folder

I need to it because on development I need POM for building project which will create jar if build pass.
In next stage I need to run that jar to another env where only jar will run so I can't use POM there and putted a main method in **Main/Java** package.

So try to trigger my **TestRunner.java** which having in **Main/java** from a **JUNIT** class from test, but due to package issue not able to do so.

I found it below but hasn't resolve my issue

[Cannot access class in test package from main package (Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027100/cannot-access-class-in-test-package-from-main-package-eclipse)

So, the structure is like below:

```
src/main/java - having TestRunner.java
src.test.java - should have a junit class which can access TesrRunner.java for Maven build
```

Cucumeer Options

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber" }, features = { "classpath:features" }, glue = { TestingConstants.GLUE })
```

Any work around will be helpful

Comment: How about executing Cucumber without the need for a runner class - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807307/how-to-run-cucumber-feature-file-from-java-code-not-from-junit-runner/46824994#46824994.

Comment: How can we do that @Grasshopper?

Comment: Instead of mentioning options in the runner. write it in a string array and pass it to main() method of the Main class of cucumber. It is in the cucumber.api.cli package.

Comment: can you please give me an example .. it will help

Comment: Add the cucumber runner options to the question...

Comment: Done ... I have updated the cucumber options in question

Comment: I have already using below method org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main("demo.IntegrationMainTest"); to trigger the junit from Main , this is for jar.

Comment: for that I am using <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId> plugin

Comment: but it this plug-in execute everything after build which I dont want so currently I have two Testrunner

Comment: This is the junit generic runner not sure if it will execute cucumber tests properly.One clarification - Are u using any junit features like BeforeClass or AfterClass in ur runner?

Comment: yes I am using BeforeSuite by implementing this manaism : http://mkolisnyk.github.io/cucumber-reports/before-after-methods

Comment: Then this approach will not work.

Comment: oh :( ... still I want to know how to run cucumber option which main method uisng array string .. may it help me during my implementation

Comment: Are you saying like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774099/pass-cucumber-options-dynamically-in-cucumber-junit

Comment: I was wrong in my statement about junit generic runner, u are using it correctly. This demo.integrationmaintest is the runner?

Comment: demo.integrationmaintest  is the package and class of TestRunner implemation. I am using this code (org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main) to trigger junit from main class